# Why would ftp_ssl_connect work on one host but not another?

Tags: php, ftp

Using `$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect('myhost.com', 2222, 180);` works like a charm on my localhost and on my test server, but when I try to do it on the live server, it returns false.  What could be the root cause?

Comment: Firewall, obviously.

Comment: Sure enough, @MartinPrikryl.  Would you please make your comment into an answer so I can give you the points?

Comment: Imo, you do not have a programming question in the first place. So this is [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue was the firewall, as Martin said.